# Как вызывать одно и то же модальное окно нажатием на разные кнопки?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Ситуация: есть одностраничник, в нем среди всего прочего 5 абсолютно одинаковых блоков с кнопкой (у кнопки один и тот же класс — .btn_sign). Нажатие на кнопку должно вызывать модальное окно.

Не могу разобраться, как сделать, чтобы **каждая** из кнопок .btn_sign вызывала окно .modal-window_entry. Пока только постигаю азы JS, поэтому туплю.
Помогите, пожалуйста)

Ниже код, вызывающий модальное окно по нажатию только на **первую** кнопку.

```
var openModalEntry = document.querySelector(".btn_sign");
var showModalEntry = document.querySelector(".modal-window_entry");
var closeModalEntry = showModalEntry.querySelector(".close-entry");

openModalEntry.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
showModalEntry.classList.add("show-entry");
});

closeModalEntry.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
showModalEntry.classList.remove("show-entry");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать цикл, который создаст функцию для каждой кнопки:

```js
var openModalEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_sign");
var showModalEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-window_entry");
var closeModalEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".close-entry");

for(var i = 0; i < openModalEntry.length; i++){
  openModalEntry[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    showModalEntry[0].classList.add("show-entry");
  });
};

for(var i = 0; i < closeModalEntry.length; i++){
  closeModalEntry[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    showModalEntry[0].classList.remove("show-entry");
  });
};
```

```css
div.modal-window_entry {display:none;}
div.modal-window_entry.show-entry {display:block;}
```

```html
<button class="btn_sign">Показать 1</button>
<button class="btn_sign">Показать 2</button>
<button class="btn_sign">Показать 3</button>

<div class="modal-window_entry">Текст <button class="close-entry">Закрыть</button></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Раз у вас несколько кнопок с одним классом, то нужно использовать `querySelectorAll`, он находит все кнопки с классом, а `querySelector` только первую.

```js
var openModalEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_sign");

openModalEntry.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="btn_sign">111</div>
<div class="btn_sign">222</div>
<div class="btn_sign">333</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Почему-то конкретно этот вариант не срабатывал.      Видимо, ошибка какая-то допущена была, теперь работает